# Ranger key mapping move multiple selected file and move without enter the return key

Tags: ranger

I want to fast move things to different folder here is my mapping

```
map mh shell -f mv %f /home/sln
map mw shell -f mv %f /home/sln/Work
map md shell -f mv %f /home/sln/Documents
map mk shell -f mv %f /home/sln/Downloads
map dD shell -f mv %f /home/sln/TrashBin //I hate delete function from Ranger ALWAYS makes accident!!!
```

**Issues:**

1. each time I need to tap the enter key to make the move action in to effect. how to make the movement happens without the enter key
2. it is not possible to move all selected files but only one by one, how to solve this in my key binding

Answer (score 1):

`m` is used by ranger to set marks (so you can quickly go to different directories with `'`)

Try to use a key that is not yet mapped by ranger. For example:

```
map Th shell -f mv %f /home/sln
```

Also, you probably don't want to run the `mv` in the background - (not sure what you mean with enter but it's probably not updating?), if so remove the `-f`:

```
map Th shell mv %f /home/sln
```

To move all selected files use `%s`:

```
map Th shell mv %s /home/sln
```